# How to use OR function for MySQL query VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem with the last bit of my code for a school project. I need to select multiple values from column "actuelewerktuigselectie", for the given IDs. Then these values need to be inserted in variables to use further in the project.

I only get the values fot the first ID. See below the code that I've now.
What can I change to fix my code to get all of the values?

```
        Dim sCnnStr As String = My.Settings.sCnnStr
        Dim oCnn As New MySqlConnection(sCnnStr)
        Dim sSql As String = "select pfProfielfreesnummer, pfLopendemeters from actuelewerktuigselectie where (awsId=@1 OR awsId=@2 OR awsId=@3 OR awsId=@4 OR awsId=@5 OR awsId=@6 OR awsId=@7 OR awsId=@8)"
        Dim oCmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sSql, oCnn)

        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", 5)
        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", 6)
        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", 7)
        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", 8)
        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", 17)
        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@6", 18)
        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@7", 19)
        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@8", 20)

        oCnn.Open()
        Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
        myReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader()
        While (myReader.Read())
            werktuignummer1 = (myReader.GetString(0))
            LopendeMeters1 = (myReader.GetDouble(1))

            werktuignummer2 = (myReader.GetString(2))
            LopendeMeters2 = (myReader.GetDouble(3))

            werktuignummer3 = (myReader.GetString(4))
            LopendeMeters3 = (myReader.GetDouble(5))

            werktuignummer4 = (myReader.GetString(6))
            LopendeMeters4 = (myReader.GetDouble(7))

            werktuignummer5 = (myReader.GetString(8))
            LopendeMeters5 = (myReader.GetDouble(9))

            werktuignummer6 = (myReader.GetString(10))
            LopendeMeters6 = (myReader.GetDouble(11))

            werktuignummer7 = (myReader.GetString(12))
            LopendeMeters7 = (myReader.GetDouble(13))

            werktuignummer8 = (myReader.GetString(14))
            LopendeMeters8 = (myReader.GetDouble(15))
        End While
        myReader.Close()
        oCnn.Close()
```

All of this code is what I taught myself in a couple of months because I didn't get the necessary courses to do this project, but I just went along with it and learned myself the very basics of vb.net and MySql.

My column and variables ar in dutch.

Comment: You could change your sql to use the IN statement: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php

Comment: Why do you think you get only the result for 1 row? I think what happens is that you override the variables in every iteration of the while loop retaining just the last row's value in the resultset.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer I've actually tried it with an IN statement before switching to the OR statement, but it gave the same result. I wrote it like this, WHERE awsId IN (@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8).

Comment: @Shadow, When I add a breakpoint and put the variables Werktuignummer1,... LopendeMeters1,... I can see that only the first variable gets filled in while all the rest remain "nothing" if its a string or "0" if its a double

Comment: How about parameter names that are not numbers?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer I tried it with just letters and I still get only the first value.

Comment: Actually I think @Shadow made a good comment. Are you not overwriting your values each time you loop in the While loop?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer shouldn't I see the last value in the first variable then if I was overwriting it? I see just the correct first value in the first variable but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have an unknown number of results, perhaps with a maximum of 8 results. So, it would be better to use something to store the results in which can expand its storage as needed for as many results as are returned from the query: you can use a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) for that, as long as you make something that you can have a list of to contain all the data for each returned row from the query - that something can be a Class with properties to hold each variable. It's probably easier to see my suggested code than explain it:

```
Public Class ToolDatum
    Public Property ToolID As String
    Public Property LopendeMeter As Double

    Public Sub New()
        ' Empty constructor
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(werktuignummer As String, LopendeMeter As Double)
        Me.ToolID = werktuignummer
        Me.LopendeMeter = LopendeMeter
    End Sub

End Class

Public Function GetData() As List(Of ToolDatum)
    Dim toolData As New List(Of ToolDatum)

    Dim connStr As String = My.Settings.sCnnStr
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT pfProfielfreesnummer, pfLopendemeters
                         FROM actuelewerktuigselectie
                         WHERE (awsId = @P1 OR awsId = @P2 OR awsId = @P3 OR awsId = @P4 OR awsId = @P5 OR awsId = @P6 OR awsId = @P7 OR awsId = @P8)"

    Using conn = New MySqlConnection(connStr),
           cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@P1", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 5
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@P2", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 6
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@P3", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 7
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@P4", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 8
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@P5", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 17
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@P6", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 18
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@P7", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 19
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@P8", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 20

        conn.Open()

        Using myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While (myReader.Read())
                toolData.Add(New ToolDatum(myReader.GetString(0), myReader.GetDouble(1)))
            End While

        End Using

    End Using

    Return toolData

End Function
```

The function GetData (you should give it a descriptive name) will return a list that you can iterate over to get each individual result, e.g.

```
Dim q = GetData()
For Each r In q
    Console.WriteLine(r.ToolID & " " & r.LopendeMeter)
Next
```

---

I changed `AddWithValue` to `Add` because the former can cause unexpected problems. I changed the parameter names to start with a letter to avoid other unexpected problems.

The [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) makes sure that things that need to have unmanaged resources disposed of are taken care of.

Comment: The number of result should always be 8 actually. I'll try to do it as your example!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your query only retrieves 2 columns but you try to get 16 values from the reader each time you read. If there will be 8 records then you need to call `Read` 8 times. If there are 2 columns then you get 2 values from the reader each time you read. If you want to use distinct variables as you are then the code to read the data should be like this:

```vb
myReader.Read()
werktuignummer1 = (myReader.GetString(0))
LopendeMeters1 = (myReader.GetDouble(1))

myReader.Read()
werktuignummer2 = (myReader.GetString(0))
LopendeMeters2 = (myReader.GetDouble(1))

myReader.Read()
werktuignummer3 = (myReader.GetString(0))
LopendeMeters3 = (myReader.GetDouble(1))

myReader.Read()
werktuignummer4 = (myReader.GetString(0))
LopendeMeters4 = (myReader.GetDouble(1))

myReader.Read()
werktuignummer5 = (myReader.GetString(0))
LopendeMeters5 = (myReader.GetDouble(1))

myReader.Read()
werktuignummer6 = (myReader.GetString(0))
LopendeMeters6 = (myReader.GetDouble(1))

myReader.Read()
werktuignummer7 = (myReader.GetString(0))
LopendeMeters7 = (myReader.GetDouble(1))

myReader.Read()
werktuignummer8 = (myReader.GetString(0))
LopendeMeters8 = (myReader.GetDouble(1))
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked without changing to much to the inital code!